# ALC tableau algorithm example

Tags: logic, owl, reasoning, description-logic

I'm trying to solve the following example using the tableau algorithm for ALC. Given the following TBox T:

```
A⊆B
A⊆C
B⊆∃R.D̸
C⊆∃R.D
E⊆∀R.D̸
```

Tell whether the concept A is satisfiable. So I put A(a) in my ABox and I start the algorithm, getting:

```
A0={((A̸∨B)∩(A̸∨C)∩(B̸∨∃R.D̸)∩(C̸∨∃R.D)∩(E̸∨∀R.D̸))(a)}.
```

Then I get:

```
A1={((A̸∨B),(A̸∨C),(B̸∨∃R.D̸),(C̸∨∃R.D),(E̸∨∀R.D̸))(a)}.
```

which leads me to:

```
Ak={((A̸(a)∨B(a)),(A̸(a)∨C(a)),(B̸(a)∨R(a,b)D(b̸)),(C̸(a)∨R(a,c)D(c)),(E̸(a)∨D̸(b)))}.
```

A̸(a) is a clash with A(a), B̸(a) is a clash with B(a) and C̸(a) is a clash with C(a), so I have:

```
Ak={((B(a)),(C(a)),(R(a,b)D(b̸)),(R(b,c)D(c)),(E̸(a)∨D̸(b)))}.
```

Let's see what happens with b's expansion:

```
Ak+1={((A̸∨B),(A̸∨C),(B̸∨∃R.D̸),(C̸∨∃R.D),(E̸∨∀R.D̸))(b)}.
```

which leads me to:

```
Ak+m={((A̸(b)∨B(b)),(A̸(b)∨C(b)),(B̸(b)∨blocked),(C̸(b)∨blocked),(E̸(b)∨D̸(c)))}.
```

Now D̸(c) clashes with D(c) and B̸(b) clashes with B(b).

And I get it is unsatisfiable, which is wrong. Could somebody please show me where I'm wrong with the application of this tableau algorithm?